# Why can't anything stat a directory created with COPY in a Dockerfile on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have several projects linked to Github repositories that build on Docker Hub via a `Dockerfile` in each project. This arrangement has been working fine, but all my builds started failing 100% of the time a while back. I've been trying to trace it and realized I didn't really do *anything* and the issue it fails on is quite basic.

I'm using the *archlinux* base image and copying the source of my app to the container using something like:

```
COPY ./ /src
```

Next I move into that directory:

```
WORKDIR /src
```

Then I try to build the software. Normally this would involve running `./configure`, but that dies with a weird error saying "Operation not permitted". It turn out this isn't just an issue for GNU Make, **even `ls` can't read the directory**! Specifically the directory, not the stuff inside it. I can run `RUN ls -l` and get a list of files in the source that got copied over, but I can't run `RUN ls -ld` to show the directory properties, it dies like this:

```
Step 17/28 : RUN ls -ald
---> Running in ec8f9f6c3604
ls: cannot access '.': Operation not permitted

Removing intermediate container ec8f9f6c3604
The command '/bin/sh -c ls -ald' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I can run various other commands, but anything that tries to look at the directory itself dies like this. I can even create files in the directory.

Note these same `Dockerfile`s build just fine on my local system using `docker build`. What gives? What is different about building them on Docker Hub?

Comment: See also [my forum post abut this issue](https://forums.docker.com/t/multiple-projects-stopped-building-on-docker-hub-operation-not-permitted/92570?u=alerque). I'll update this if there are any solutions.